# Sitemap with an App using Codeigniter and jQuery Mobile?

Tags: web-crawlers, jquery, codeigniter

We've got dynamic content that we want the google bot to search.  Our app is running codeingiter and jQuery mobile.

So, our site is basically 6 pages that are updated using XHR calls.  The data is populated within the main page itself.  Any ideas on how I can make all the data in the pages addressable?

Thanks in advance,

Scott.